# Black Screen on VNC (SUSE Linux)

Tags: opensuse, vnc, suse

I used to be able to connect to my server using a VNC Client. However, now the window will open but is (and stays) black.

I can SSH to my server. I restarted vncserver with no effect. I used cat on the logfile which is pasted below.

I appreciate your help debugging the problem.

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.6.0 - built ??? ?? ???? ??:??:??
Copyright (C) 1999-2015 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11803000, The X.Org Foundation


Wed Jul 25 11:57:20 2018
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on all interface(s), port 5801
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/etc/X11/xim: Checking whether an input method should be started.
/etc/X11/xim: Checking whether an input method is specified in /home/user/.i18n.
sourcing /etc/sysconfig/language to get the value of INPUT_METHOD
INPUT_METHOD is not set or empty (no user selected input method).
Trying to start a default input method for the locale en_US.UTF-8 ...
There is no default input method for the current locale.
Dummy input method "none" (do not use any fancy input method by default)
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-binary[17070]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

** (gnome-session-failed:17123): WARNING **: Cannot open display:

Wed Jul 25 11:57:31 2018
 Connections: accepted: 10.16.51.124::49316
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Wed Jul 25 11:57:36 2018
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888

Wed Jul 25 11:57:37 2018
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888

Wed Jul 25 11:57:56 2018
 Connections: closed: 10.16.51.124::49316 (Clean disconnection)
 EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 1
 EncodeManager:   Tight:
 EncodeManager:     Solid: 1 rects, 786.432 kpixels
 EncodeManager:            16 B (1:196609 ratio)
 EncodeManager:   Total: 1 rects, 786.432 kpixels
 EncodeManager:          16 B (1:196609 ratio)
```

Comment: The log says: "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused". Is your server correctly initialized and running?

Comment: How do I check that? Is there a command you can give me?

Comment: Yes, there probably is such a command, but I'm not 100% sure about that. Sorry, can't help you there. Don't want to guide you to a wrong direction.